# Make Text inside a button responsive in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a problem with the text inside the button. When I resize the window browser, the text goes outside from the button and all father container.

```
<button id="addFleetButton" type="button"
    class="btn btn-primary col-xs-1 col-xs-offset-11"
    data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addFleetModal">Add fleet</button>
```

Is there a way to automatically fix this problem with bootstrap? I wouldn't like to change css to obtain the aim.
Thanks

UPGRADE: given that if I resize the text when the resolution decrease it doesn't show well, I've created this code:

```
<button id="addFleetButton" type="button"
    class="btn btn-primary visible-lg col-lg-1 col-lg-offset-11"
    data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addFleetModal">Add fleet</button>
<button id="addFleetButton" type="button"
    class="btn btn-primary hidden-lg col-xs-1 col-xs-offset-11"
    data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addFleetModal" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Add fleet">+</button>
```

So when I am on desktop resolution I see "Add fleet" into button, otherwise I see "+" and a tooltip with text "Add fleet".
What do you thihk about?

Comment: No Bootstrap method. you'd need to reduce the font-size in the media query.

Comment: the col-xs-1 col-xs-offset-11 give button a width, so change this? or add some other col width?

Comment: The size change with the browser resolution, so the text doesn't fill in the box. I tried font-size: 1vw; but resize ever the button so it become too small

Comment: You have no choice but to change `col-xs-1` and `col-xs-offset-11` to something more realistic and/or include other `col-*` classes for each breakpoint.

Comment: I updated with a possibile solution. What do you think?